# Notation for a matrix times nabla

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector function.
What does the notation

$$(A\nabla)u$$

mean?

Comment: $\nabla$ is usually used for gradient. Is $u$ a function of something? If not, more context is needed.

Comment: $A\nabla$ could be a column vector with components $\sum_ja_{ij} \partial_j$ but it won't apply to a column vector $u$. So some transposition is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it would be something like that , and i hope this is helpful.

TO give an example in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times2}$ 
$$  \begin{pmatrix} a && b\\c && d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{1} \\ \partial_{2} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a\partial_{1}+b \partial_{2} \\ c \partial_{1} + d  \partial_{2} \end{pmatrix}$$
and times u :
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a\partial_{1}+b \partial_{2} \\ c \partial_{1} + d  \partial_{2} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_{1} \\ u_{2} \end{pmatrix} = (a\partial_{1}+b \partial_{2})u_{1} +  (c \partial_{1} + d  \partial_{2})u_{2} $$
But $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ need to be functions, or it gives zero...

If this wasn't helpful, may you give us some context ? Like the entire question ?

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way of interpreting this is that $\nabla u$, when $u$ is a vector, generates a tensor of the following form (using index notation):
$$\nabla u = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Consequently, $A$ is a linear operator/matrix acting on $\nabla u$, which is well-defined under the rules of matrix multiplication since they both have the same "dimensionality". Again using index notation, this multiplication looks like:

$$\left[(A\nabla)u\right]_{kj} = A_{ki}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Comment: So, it should be the same as the product of matrices $A(\nabla u)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but it is difficult to say for certain without additional context from the source.